# Решение найдено this.setState ({id: event.currentTarget.id}) удаляет старый id

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Пожалуйста помоги!

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку добавить в корзину, я беру id товара и без проблем переношу его в корзину, но когда я нажимаю на другой товар, id с состоянием заменяется на новый id и получается, что новый товар не добавляется в корзину, а просто заменяется старым на новый =(

Я понимаю, что currentTarget берет id, но при повторном вызове заменяет его новым id. Вопрос: как сохранить прошлый id в состоянии?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      selectValue: "$ USD",
      count: 0,
      id: [],
      basketItems: [] 
    };
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({selectValue: e.target.value})
  }
    clickCartId = (event) => {
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          basketItems: [...prevState, {id: event.currentTarget.id}]
        }
      })
    }
```

Это то что ClickCart отслеживает `<div className={products.inStock ? s.circleCartTrue : s.circleCartFalse} id={products.id} onClick={this.props.clickId}>`

Это конечный получатель `this.state.products.map((products) => (              value.state.basketItems === products.id ?` Тут дальше идет тернароное выражение

Comment: Для функционала корзины думаю стоит сохранять id'шники в массив. При клике на кнопку вызывать функцию, которая в state будет сохранять предыдущее состояние и новое.

Comment: У меня сохраняет id в state. Но сохраняет id товара только того на который пользователь нажал, если добавить другой товар, то старый товар заменится на новый. Как мне сохранить старое значение в state и при этом добавлялось новое?

Comment: Я решил самостоятельно вопрос использовав concat

CartId = (event) => {
    this.setState ({cartItems: this.state.cartItems.concat(event.currentTarget.id)})}

Кто столкнулся с той же проблемой можете взглянуть мой код который был и каким он стал.
Марсель благодарю что пытался помочь.